# My bootstrap PHP contact form comes back with 404 - File or directory not found

Tags: php, forms, http-status-code-404, contacts

Can anyone help with a php error. My contact form comes back with

404 - File or directory not found

This is my form

```
      <form action="contact.php" class="contact-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail1">Your Name: *</label>
          <input required type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Your Name: *">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail1">Email: *</label>
          <input required type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email: *">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail1">Subject:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Subject:">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea required class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Message: *"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>
```

and this is my PHP

```
<?php

$mail = "jade@------.CO.UK";

if($_POST['message']) {
        $message = "<h2>Hello here is a message from ".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."</h2><hr>
                    <p><strong>Name:</strong> ".$_POST['name']."</p>
                    <p><strong>Email:</strong> ".$_POST['email']."</p>
                    <p><strong>Message:</strong> ".$_POST['message']."</p>";
        $subject="Premium template message: ".$_POST['subject'];
        mail($mail, $subject, $message, "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8 \r\n");
        echo 'AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA';
}
?>
```

I'm quite new to this and its driving me crazy.

Thanks

Comment: your code is failing for more reasons than one. One of which I have my doubts about.

Comment: can you help? its driving me crazy

Comment: Sure. A few things; no name attributes for your inputs and unsure as to how you're accessing these files as. If you don't have a webserver/php installed; that's an issue. If you do have those installed, then the way you're accessing them is important. `http://localhost` is what should be used, as opposed to `file:///`, if that's what you're doing. I can't see any other reason why your code would fail besides what I said here. Also, filenames can be case-sensitive depending on your OS, check that.

Comment: I've left the question now. Sorry, but I can't sit and stare at the comments area for much longer. Good luck with this.

Comment: Thank yo so much for you help. I use a fasthost server so literally just upload my files to the htdoc folder. Would i just need to keep my php file on my local drive rather than put to the remote server?

Answer (score 0):

Your form doesn't have a method. Since you are posting data, add the POST method in html like this

```
<form action="contact.php" method="POST" class="contact-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
```

And hope that contact.php is in the same directory as well.

Comment: Thanks for your help. i've done what you've said but now getting this error 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.

Comment: What kind of server are you using?

Comment: just a fastest package

Comment: What is the extension of the html file? If its html, rename it to php and then try. And hope that is a apache server.

Answer (score 0):

Check the proper relative `contact.php` file location. If you are submiting the form to the same file you are in then just remove `action="contact.php"`. Also you need to add `method`. Here's how it should be. Mark `action` and `method` in the below code.

`<form action="" method="post" class="contact-form" accept-charset="UTF-8" role="form">
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail1">Your Name: *</label>
          <input required type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Your Name: *">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
          <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail1">Email: *</label>
          <input required type="email" class="form-control" id="inputEmail1" placeholder="Email: *">
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="sr-only" for="exampleInputEmail1">Subject:</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputName" placeholder="Subject:">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <textarea required class="form-control" rows="5" placeholder="Message: *"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">Submit</button>
      </form>`

Comment: Thanks for your help. i've done what you've said but now getting this error 405 - HTTP verb used to access this page is not allowed.